# WP simple theme, change image behaviour

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the homepage of the theme "WP simple" there is an image that is set to cover the full width of the visible area.

I would like to change the behavior and to block the maximum width to a certain amount of pixels.

I was able to find the html that handle the image, but I can't figure out what handles the resize, if it is done by javascript/jquery or by css and the inspect tool of the browser isn't helping to find the issue.

Someone is able to help me pinpoint the location where i need to make changes?

```
<section class="frontpage-banner parallax_active" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://mysite.loc/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/my-image.jpg" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); padding-top: 288.667px; padding-bottom: 288.667px;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner-wrap" style="visibility: visible; "></div>      
</div>    
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for wp themes usually width is generated by javascript code or css @media rules however you could override that by adding value in style attribute with !important tag :-

```
style="max-width:100px !important;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)..."
```